# Travelling Salesperson - Why greedy algos are not guaranteed to give an optimal solution?

Tags: optimization, greedy

Why is there no greedy algorithm that is guaranteed to give an optimal solution for the travelling salesperson problem? Is there an example for that?

Comment: Which TSP (general, metric, euclidean etc) and which greedy algorithm (NN, adding the smallest edge that doesn't ruin the tour, deciding whether to take an edge or not based on what look least-bad in terms of the linear relaxation, etc)?

Comment: Greedy algorithms aren´t neither complete nor optimal because they will choose the locally best option discarding the others for each node. If you want to obtain an optimal solution you must add backtracking. This way you get all the solutions and you can select the optimal one.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the travelling salesman problem does not satisfy the properties necessary to prove the correctness of a greedy algorithm. In order for a greedy algorithm to be correct, it must both satisfy the greedy-choice property (the first choice in your algorithm can always be in an optimal solution), and the optimal substructure property (an optimal solution to a problem contains optimal solutions to each sub problem).

While the travelling salesman does satisfy the optimal substructures property, no algorithm for this problem can satisfy the greedy choice property. Greedy algorithms require discarding other potential solutions to each sub-problem, and Traveling Salesman is too complex to do so.

A general algorithm for the Traveling salesman is to choose a starting point, generate all (n-1)! permutations of cities to visit, calculate each one's cost, then return the cheapest permutation. The running time for this algorithm is Θ(n!).

The decision version of the traveling salesperson problem is an NP-Complete problem (in this version, given a length X, does a given list of cities have a distance less than or equal to X). NP is short for "non-deterministic polynomial", and a problem in NP means that, given an answer to the problem, you can verify whether or not the certificate is correct in polynomial time. NP-Complete is the hardest class of problems in NP, and no NP-complete problem can be solved in polynomial time.